# Chrome extension XHR status 200 but not log on Apache logs

Tags: javascript, php, apache, google-chrome

I'm developing a Chrome extension (my first) and I don't understand one thing.

I call a PHP page on my server with XHR (fetch have the same result). My console says that's this request is OK with status 200, but I have no log of this request on my Apache log.

When I call the page by myself directly on the address bar, I see the page on the Apache log, and the PHP script doing its job.

My javascript code (chrome extension):

```
var url "http://server/page.php?t=[token]";    
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) { console.log(xhr.status); }
}
xhr.onerror = function () { console.log("Error 1"); };
xhr.send();
```

The data of the PHP page is:

```
{ "error": "0" } // Or 1 / 2
```

Have you already saw the same issue or do you understand what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.